# unsigned char value in a function

Tags: c

This is taken from: https://exploreembedded.com/wiki/AVR_C_Library DS1307_GetTime() method, im trying to understand how this function works. So i made a simplified example below.

Can you explain what is happening in the  GetTime() function and what kid of value should  I pass into it?

My goal is to obtain b value inside *int main()* function.

My understanding so far is:

pointer * a *= I2C_Read();* points to unsigned char, but a pointer can not point to a value, why isnt it erroring?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

unsigned char I2C_Read()
{
    unsigned char b = 0b11111111;
    return b;
}

void GetTime(unsigned char *a)
{
    *a = I2C_Read();
}

int main()
{
    unsigned char *a = 0;   
    GetTime(a);                        // ?

    printf("Value of b is: %d\n" , b); // ?
}
```

Comment: your code deferences a null pointer. It would be better to call `GetTime` with the address of an unsigned char variable, instead of with a null pointer.

Comment: "_...but a pointer can not point to a value_" Huh??? But that is exctly what a pointer is for: to _point_ to a value, be that an array element, a struct or, as here, an unsigned char.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the pointer `a` to `0` - not a valid value

You need to read up about pointers - but in the meantime change the code to

```
 unsigned char a = 0;   
 GetTime(&a);
 printf("Value of b is: %d\n" , a);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Change the main function as :**

```
int main()
{
   unsigned char a = 0; //   
   GetTime(&a);  // call by reference concept
   printf("Value of b is: %d\n" , a); 
}
```

This would result into b =  255 , if you want to print the character then replace the %d --> %c .
Maybe it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Aa I get it now, thank you

```
1) GetTime(&a);                    // pass  in address of a.
2) GetTime(unsigned char *a)       // takes in contents of a, at the moment = 0
3) *a = read();                    // set contents of a to unsigned char 0b11111111 
4) printf("Value of b: %d\n" , a); // call this from main func results in returned value b = 255
```